# Google Sheets Publish as CSV -> MS Excel Get Data (web) with sheets CSV link - cannot use imported data in formulas

Tags: excel

Google Sheets 'published to web' for one sheet with alphanumeric data only

In Excel, Get Data (Web) with Google Sheet's CSV link.

Data imports into excel brilliantly. Cannot graph with the data or use the imported cells within formulas.

All cells are set to "numbers". If I reference those cells using =A3+A4, it works, but if I do =sum(A3,A4), all I get are zeros. WHen I try and graph the data, all cells show '0'

Comment: Your data is text.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've got them converted to numbers and it works fine. Although next time I refresh the data, it'll default to text. Is there any way I can force it to pull in as numbers?